# the torsion tensor,a wikipedia article `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_tensor`

Tags: manifolds, tensors, curvature

I'm not a native English speaker. Can someone please explain to me what does this sentence mean:

*The notion of curvature measures how moving frames "roll" along a curve "without twisting".*

Comment: This title doesn’t describe the question to users on the home page. You should also point out which words, or word combinations don’t make sense to you: it is difficult to address the language barrier otherwise

Comment: @FShrike This is the trouble: `"roll" along a curve "without twisting"`.

Comment: It means what is shown in [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Parallel_Transport.svg/800px-Parallel_Transport.svg.png) picture, but with a frame rather than a single vector